# How to organize Perl modules

Tags: perl

I have a directory structure like this:

```
/path/to/lib/perl5/5.22.1
```

I have installed some perl modules in that directory in a particular format:

```
ls
Data-UUID  IPC-System-Simple  JSON  Log-Message  Math-Gradient  Term-UI
```

For example, if you go inside JSON, the directory looks like this:

```
/path/to/lib/perl5/5.22.1/JSON/2.53
```

All my modules are organized like this:

```
/path/to/lib/perl5/5.22.1/Module-name/Module-version/...
```

I have added /path/to/lib/perl5/5.22.1 to my PERL5LIB like this:

```
export PERL5LIB=/path/to/lib/perl5/5.22.1:$PERL5LIB
```

But my scripts are not able to find the perl modules. Do you think the directory structure is a problem? I just made this structure so that I have it organized as perl-module-name/module-version. Suggestions are much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given the names of the directories listed:

> Data-UUID  IPC-System-Simple  JSON  Log-Message  Math-Gradient  Term-UI

It looks like you **haven't** installed the modules at all. It looks like you've downloaded the package tarballs, extracted them, and then **not run the installers**.

You need to go into each directory and:

```
perl Makefile.PL
make
make test
make install
```

Better yet, install them using [cpanm](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Menlo/script/cpanm-menlo) or another of the programs that download modules, resolve their dependancies and install them for you.

Comment: Actually I did run the installers. These are the names of the directories, because I set my PREFIX in perl Makefile.PL such that it creates a module directory name/version/installation-happens-here.

Comment: Then you need to include *every single one* of your `module directory name/version/installation-happens-here` directories in your PERL5LIB path.

Comment: Yes, exactly that is what I was confused about. What I thought was that I can create specific directories for installation and just put the parent folder name in PERL5LIB path and that perl will search for modules starting from the parent folder and so on. So, what is the best practice if I just want one single library folder?

Comment: To not change PREFIX all the time.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will just create one library folder and then install all my modules in it.

Answer (score 4):

Perl requires a specific directory structure within the path specified by `PERL5LIB`. For instance `IPC-System-Simple` must be installed in a file `IPC/System/Simple.pm`. etc. You can't just go making up directory structures and hope Perl can work out your structure and find what it needs

Comment: Ok I understand now. Thanks!