# Perl module installation structure and version control

Tags: perl

I am just starting to organize some stuff on the cluster and would like some advice on it. I posted a recent question [How to organize Perl modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34406049/how-to-organize-perl-modules) and got some good answers about what I was doing incorrectly. I was trying to install each perl module independently by setting the `PREFIX` for `Makefile.PL` each time to `/path/to/lib/module-name/module-version/installation happens here`.

For e.g. for a module JSON, I installed it like this:

```
perl Makefile.PL --PREFIX=/path/to/lib/perl5/5.22.1/JSON/2.53
make
make test
make install
```

For module Data-UUID, I did it like this:

```
perl Makefile.PL --PREFIX=/path/to/lib/perl5/5.22.1/Data-UUID/1.221
make
make test
make install
```

So it made a directory JSON/2.53 in /path/to/lib/perl5/5.22.1 and that's where it installed the package. But because I change the PREFIX for each individual module, I have to set the `PATH` in the bash_profile accordingly, which is kind of messy.

My main goal to do this was for version control. In a hypothetical scenario where different versions work for two of your teammates, say JSON/2.52 works for X and JSON/2.53 works for Y, how do you control for versions without having to ask them to install their versions locally? In another scenario, what if a version worked for you 3 months back and the updated version doesn't work for you anymore? How do you keep track of versions if you install everything in one directory?

I also have more questions on the module local::lib but I will post it as another question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maintaining concurrent versions of CPAN modules is asking for grief. I would suggest instead - don't, use `docker` for anything that's got any sort of deployment. That way you can have local installation of stuff + deps in an isolated container.

It's a bit like early days yet on `docker`, but they're a significant amount of enthusiasm and support for it from some very big names.

Personally I'm just using it to bundle up "mojolicious" perl webapps behind a reverse proxy, and maintain their dependencies as a self contained installation (which I can run/test/deploy autonomously)

Comment: I think I will have to read through the answer a couple more times atleast to understand it. I am really bad at understanding technical terms, but what I did understand is that I should look into docker :) Thanks!!